# Issue migration 2.4.1 to 2.4.4

Tags: magento2, admin, magento2.4, magento2.4.4, static-content-deploy

I'm facing several issues in my migration process from 2.4.1 to 2.4.4.

On the backend, when I try to login :

- If wrong credentials: error message; this is fine.
- If proper credentials, then, the url change for the dashbord url, but I stay on the login page. No error in logs.

Already tried to clean cache and remove cookies. Same behavior with all browsers.

=========

In the frontend, the theme is broken, and I can see it in system.

```
[2022-11-04T13:45:25.711061+00:00] main.ERROR: No matching definition was found for `@family-name:'luma-icons', @font-path:'../fonts/Luma-Icons', @font-weight:normal, @font-style:normal, @font-display:block` in _icons.less on line 7, column 5
05| 
06| & when (@media-common = true) {
07|     .lib-font-face(
08|         @family-name: @icons__font-name,
09|         @font-path: @icons__font-path,
10|         @font-weight: normal, [] []
[2022-11-04T13:45:25.711334+00:00] main.CRITICAL: No matching definition was found for `@family-name:'luma-icons', @font-path:'../fonts/Luma-Icons', @font-weight:normal, @font-style:normal, @font-display:block` in _icons.less on line 7, column 5
05| 
06| & when (@media-common = true) {
07|     .lib-font-face(
08|         @family-name: @icons__font-name,
09|         @font-path: @icons__font-path,
10|         @font-weight: normal, [] []
```

EDIT

```
magento@de610b81bd24:/var/www/magento$ rm -rf var/view_preprocessed/pub/static/frontend
magento@de610b81bd24:/var/www/magento$ rm -rf pub/static/frontend
magento@de610b81bd24:/var/www/magento$ bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f --area frontend

Deploy using quick strategy
frontend/Magento/blank/fr_FR            2341/2341           ============================ 100%   13 secs           
frontend/Magento/luma/fr_FR             2357/2357           ============================ 100%   14 secs           
frontend/Nespresso/default/fr_FR        2259/2766           ======================>----- 81%    8 secs
Compilation from source: /var/www/magento/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/web/css/styles-m.less
No matching definition was found for `@family-name:'luma-icons', @font-path:'../fonts/Luma-Icons', @font-weight:normal, @font-style:normal, @font-display:block` in _icons.less on line 7, column 5
05| 
06| & when (@media-common = true) {
07|     .lib-font-face(
08|         @family-name: @icons__font-name,
frontend/Magento/blank/fr_FR            2341/2341           ============================ 100%   13 secs           
frontend/Magento/luma/fr_FR             2357/2357           ============================ 100%   14 secs           
frontend/Nespresso/default/fr_FR        2766/2766           ============================ 100%   11 secs

Execution time: 44.267537117004
```

[image: screen full]

EDIT : My custom typography

```
//
//  Typography
//  _____________________________________________

.lib-font-face(
    @family-name,
    @font-path,
    @font-weight: normal,
    @font-style: normal
) {
    @font-face {
        font-family: @family-name;
        src: url('@{font-path}.eot');
        src: url('@{font-path}.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('@{font-path}.woff2') format('woff2'),
        url('@{font-path}.woff') format('woff'),
        url('@{font-path}.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('@{font-path}.svg#@{family-name}') format('svg');
        font-weight: @font-weight;
        font-style: @font-style;
    }
}
```

And here is the magento one

```
//
//  Typography
//  _____________________________________________

.lib-font-face(
    @family-name,
    @font-path,
    @font-format: false,
    @font-weight: normal,
    @font-style: normal,
    @font-display: auto,
    @font-type: false
) when (@font-format = false) {
    @font-face {
        font-family: @family-name;
        src: url('@{font-path}.woff2') format('woff2'),
        url('@{font-path}.woff') format('woff');
        font-weight: @font-weight;
        font-style: @font-style;
        font-display: @font-display;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. For admin login issue in Magento 2.4.4: This issue reported in Magento github https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/35297

> Found the issue! In Magento 2.4.4 it seems that a value of "0" for
> "Max Session Size in Admin" breaks it. In normal behaviour "0" should
> disable the size. I set mine now to "2560000" cause the default
> setting of "256000" isn't working for us (too low) and that solved
> this issue for now.
>
> You can set it to this value through CLI (flush cache after):

```
bin/magento config:set system/security/max_session_size_admin 2560000
```

2. For the theme issue:
   Compare `<your custom theme dir>/web/css/source/lib/_typography.less` with `vendor/magento/magento2-base/lib/web/css/source/lib/_typography.less`, and update the changes that changed from Magento codebase (core) recently. In case you don't know how to check, add `<your custom theme dir>/web/css/source/lib/_typography.less` content in your post, I'll take a look.

Comment: how am i supposed to check this ? I asked for an integrator to check it too and he didn't understood neither where the issue came from. Our theme is extending luma.How can i check if luma has the good information ? Thanks for your assistance :)

Comment: I've updated my answer, please check.

Comment: The error is now showing directly on compilation see my question edited to get the full trace

Comment: I've added solution for Admin login issue, please give it a try. Please add a screenshot for `lib` and `components` folders inside `web/css/source` folder too.

Comment: Admin solution works. Thank you very much ! screen added

Comment: Cheers. Let's check the update in my answer.

Comment: I tried to update myself my typography.less but i'm now getting `[2022-11-04T15:33:17.374153+00:00] main.CRITICAL: Operation on an invalid type in _typography.less in _utilities.less in _slick.less [] []
` so i guess my update is wrong. I've edited with my original typographuy + the magento one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140366/discussion-between-tu-van-and-claims).

Comment: @Claims let's back to the chat box, I've added a new update.

Comment: We have other issues but somehow looks like remove typography.less file from lib  is doing the job now. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Glad to hear that. Cheers. Did you seen the tip for deploy theme I was sent yesterday?